distorted sine of 230V phase
I measured a distortion at the secondary of a 230V AC supply (a transformer in a housing, nothing more).
So I connected its primary to a frequency generator and voila, a nice sine as expected.

And here is the distorted sine measured when the power supply is plugged to a 230V socket:

The Question is simple, what causes you can think of. The only larger active loads in my house are my desktop PC (with PFC), my TV and a analog HiFi Amplifier. I wonder if any of these could cause such an distortion. So I just want to get some fresh ideas and opinions.
additional note: there are Type 1&2 + Type 3 (at the sockets) surge arresters in my house

But there are unknown things. First of all, how do you know if the transformer distorts the mains waveform, if you have not measured the mains waveform if it is distorted or not before the transformer? Note, it's highly dangerous and requires clear plan about correct tools and which scope probes to use and how so I recommend not to do it. But if you have measured it, where the distortion happened?

@Justme well I am educated in electrics and I have all tools needed... but still I do not tinker around with 230V if I can avoid it. But Maybe I should setup a measurement...


The Question is simple, what causes you can think of.

If it's a cheap transformer that is low power then the series losses together with the onset of core saturation could cause this. If it's a decent transformer then it's likely your mains AC that is distorted (less likely).

The only larger active loads in my house are my desktop PC (with PFC), my TV and a analog HiFi Amplifier. I wonder if any of these could cause such an distortion.

Unlikely but, if your AC supply is really flakey then, they could cause an effect.

it could be the transformer staurating and distorting the signal if you can configure the transformer for a higher primary voltage, that should reduce the amount of distortion.  Alternatively add another identical transformer in series.
The cause of the distortion might not be in your house.  If you're sufficiently curious you could turn off all the other loads in your house and see what happens.
